# Exporting Dataframe into multiple excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, histogram

I have a small sized dataframe of approximately 27 columns in the excel file. I'm actually pretty new to coding and needed help in separating one dataframe into various excel file BASED on the Column numbers of the dataframe. I tried a small code that gives me the same error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl
from pandas import ExcelWriter

data = pd.read_excel('/Users/jorge/Desktop/Data/Book1.xlsx')
counts, bins, patches = plt.hist(data.values, bins=range(0, 
int(max(data.values)+5), 5))
df = pd.DataFrame({'bin_leftedge': bins[:-1], 'count': counts})
df.columns= np.arange(0, len(data.columns))
for i in range (0, 27):
    name = '/Users/user/Desktop/Data/t40-%d.xlsx' % (i+1)
    print (name)
    print (header[i])

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(name)
    df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2',columns=header[i])
    writer.save()
```

Which names the columns of the dataframe and tries to export EACH columns as a separate file, but I keep getting the error:

```
 AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong and how can I make it so after it makes the histogram with the appropriate bins it exports the result into different excel files based on the number of columns, so there would be 27 excel files for 27 columns. Please any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: looks like `data` is a `Series` object and not a DataFrame. Which line of code giving you the error?

Comment: Actually that is still a problem, but I also get the error                    ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 1 elements                                                                                                             and this error is from line 11

Comment: @J.Garcia Try again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

data = pd.read_excel('/Users/jorge/Desktop/Data/Book1.xlsx',header=None)
for i in data.columns:
     name = '/Users/user/Desktop/Data/t40-'+str(i+1)+'.xlsx'
     writer = pd.ExcelWriter(name)
     pd.DataFrame(data[i]).to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
     writer.save()
```

Comment: Hey bud, thanks for responding, I changed the code to your recommendations and got the same problem as the suggestion above it comes out in line 11, with the error                                                                      ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 1 elements                                                                                                    I tried looking for an answer to the code but came up short. Even if I take off the len() function it pops out: TypeError: 'Float64Index' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @J.Garcia can you tell me what the column names are?

Comment: @J.Garcia The code above is a stand alone code developed to perform the function you asked , it can't be merged with your code. Just run it independently to get the desired results. Thanks

Comment: the column names are basically the letters of the columns in an excel file I didn't name the columns imdependent from the lettering of the excel file. Is there anyway I could implement it into my code to get the desired results after binning? Thank you again

Comment: @J.Garcia Binning is not needed, I have edited the code run it again. this should handle your condition

Answer (score 0):

Change for loop with this one

```
for i in range (0, 27):
    name = '/Users/user/Desktop/Data/t40-%d.xlsx' % (i+1)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(name)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df[i])
    df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2',index = False, header = False)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Hey bud, I tried changing the loop to what you said, but I got another error associated with the line 11   df.columns= range (0, len(data.columns))              with the error                                                                      
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 1 elements, which I have no idea how to fix I'm pretty sure it has to do with the len() function of the code.